# boolean OUT parameter from procedure to mapping in java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, plsql, callable-statement

I am returning a boolean OUT parameter from PLSQL procedure to java program. I see that it is returning error as Invalid Column type. Am i doing something wrong.

```
 CallableStatement cs=null;
 cs = this.Conn.prepareCall("{ call PR_VALIDATE (?,?,?) }");
 cs.setString(1,filename);
 cs.setInt(2,fileid);
 cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.BOOLEAN);
 cs.execute();
```

I am getting below exception,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

In procedure this is IN OUT parameters,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PR_VALIDATE
(
FILENAME IN VARCHAR2(50),
FILEID IN NUMBER,
REJECT_STATUS OUT BOOLEAN
)
....................
```

Comment: "PL/SQL Boolean Types
PL/SQL has a type for representing Boolean values (true and false). Because SQL does not have an equivalent type, you can use BOOLEAN variables and parameters in PL/SQL contexts but not inside SQL statements or queries." from: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG Could this be the reason?

Comment: Thank you, but i am using Boolean only inside PLSQL block and not inside SQL.